# Column names instead of column headers as range

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code that searches a column in a sheet using the col range as value. Instead of that, I need to use the col name (in that sheet) as he search criteria and perform the same function.

I tried a different approach to do this and I'm getting syntax error.

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
Sub WBR()
Dim Count1Criteria As Variant
Dim Count3Criteria As Variant
Dim test As Variant
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

Filter3InSummary = Array(Array("AE43", "TT", "I:I", "<>Duplicate TT", _
                                     "G:G", "<>Not Tested", _
                                     "U:U", "Item"))
For Each test In Filter3InSummary
With Worksheets(test(1))
Range(test(0)) = wf.CountIfs(.Range(test(2)), test(3), _
                             .Range(test(4)), test(5), _
                             .Range(test(6)), test(7))
End With
Next
```

CODE WHERE I'M GETTING SYNTAX ERROR :

```
Sub WBR()
Dim Count1Criteria As Variant
Dim Count3Criteria As Variant
Dim test As Variant
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

Filter3InSummary = Array(Array("AE43", "TT", "Cname1", "<>Duplicate TT", _
                                     "Cname2", "<>Not Tested", _
                                     "Cname3", "Item"))
For Each test In Filter3InSummary
With Worksheets(test(1))

Range(test(0)) = wf.CountIfs(.rows(1).Find(test(2),lookat:xlWhole).EntireColu‌​mn), test(3), _ .rows(1).Find(test(2),lookat:xlWhole).EntireColumn), test(5), _ .rows(1).Find(test(2),lookat:xlWhole).EntireColumn), test(7))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have extra closing parenthesis after each `EntireColumn` and you are missing the equal signs for each named parameter.

```
Range(test(0)) = _
wf.CountIfs( _
.Rows(1).Find(test(2), lookat:=xlWhole).EntireColumn, test(3), _
.Rows(1).Find(test(2), lookat:=xlWhole).EntireColumn, test(5), _
.Rows(1).Find(test(2), lookat:=xlWhole).EntireColumn, test(7))
```